# How to allocate unallocated disk space for Vmware VM

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, disk-space

In virtual machine Windows sees disk space is 40Gb but on host VM files are actually 23Gb. Is there a way I can allocate this unallocated space after creating VM obviously?

Host and Guest are Windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` command-line utility (located in the VMware Workstation installation folder) to convert a *sparse* virtual disk file to a *pre-allocated* virtual disk.

**Warning:** The steps below will break existing snapshots.  Additionally, it is not advisable to take snapshots of a virtual machine that uses preallocated virtual disks.

Power off the virtual machine, and then run:

`vmware-vdiskmanager -r sourceDisk.vmdk -t 2 destinationDisk.vmdk`

Afterward you need to modify the VM to use the new disk by doing one of:

- In VMware Workstation, go to VM > Settings > Hardware, remove the original virtual disk and then add the new disk. (Be sure to use the same bus type (IDE vs. SCSI vs. SATA) and disk node as the original disk.)
- Close the VM in VMware Workstation, open the VM's `.vmx` file in a text editor, and change references to the old `.vmdk` file to use the new one.

Comment: This command created single 40gb file. That will do it BUT is there also a way to make it split files? Such as `win7x642-s001.vmdk` and 002 etc.

Comment: Ok in the code you mentioned `-t 2` creates monolithic disk. I will go with `-t 3` as it will make it split and preallocated disk. More information here http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006898